Setting color of feature of polygon layer with PyQGIS
I'm working on QGIS v. 3.36, I'd like change the color of a feature of a polygon layer called "canvas", but creating QgsMarkerSymbol and setting the renderer, the symbol on the map is deleted. Here is my code:
canvas = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:3003", "canv", "memory")
dimY = 20700
dimX = 70000        
cDp = canvas.dataProvider()
gb.colorCanvas(canvas, dimX, dimY, cDp)

def colorCanvas(layerInput, dimX, dimY, dp):
  simboloCanvas = QgsMarkerSymbol.createSimple({'name': 'rounded_square', 'color' 
  :'green'})
    punti = []
    puntoA = QgsPointXY(-500, -1000)
    puntoB = QgsPointXY(-500, dimY+ 1000)
    puntoC = QgsPointXY(dimX+1000, -1000)
    puntoD = QgsPointXY(dimX+1000, dimY + 1000)
    punti.append(puntoA)
    punti.append(puntoB)
    punti.append(puntoD)
    punti.append(puntoC)
        
    poli = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([punti])
    poligono = QgsFeature(layerInput.fields())
    poligono.setGeometry(poli)
    dp.addAttributes([QgsField("Id", QVariant.Int)])
    poligono.setAttributes([1])
    dp.addFeatures([poligono])
    with edit(layerInput):
        for feat in layerInput.getFeatures():
            colorR = 174
            colorG = 180
            colorB = 183
            print("questa è una feature")
            simboloCanvas.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(colorR, colorG, colorB))
            
    layerInput.renderer().setSymbol(simboloCanvas)
    
    layerInput.updateFeature(feat)
    layerInput.triggerRepaint()
    layerInput.endEditCommand() # Stop editing
    layerInput.commitChanges() # Save changes



There are a number of issues with your code, but the main one is that you are trying to use a QgsMarkerSymbol for a polygon layer. QgsMarkerSymbol is for point geometry; for polygons you need QgsFillSymbol.
You can create a QgsFillSymbol object like so:
simboloCanvas = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'color':'174,180,183,255', 'outline_color':'35,35,35,255', 'outline_style':'solid', 'outline_width':'0.26', 'outline_width_unit':'MM', 'style':'solid'})

Or by using the static method QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(), passing the layer's geometry type then setting the color e.g.
simboloCanvas = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layerInput.geometryType())
simboloCanvas.setColor(QColor(174, 180, 183))

Other problems:
The code produces an invalid polygon with a self intersection.
Don't mix data provider and layer editing methods (in fact you don't need the layer in edit mode to set the symbol color).
You don't need to iterate features.
After adding a new field you need to call updateFields() on the layer object.
This line: gb.colorCanvas(canvas, dimX, dimY, cDp) suggests that colorCanvas() is a class method. If so, you are missing the self (instance) argument in the function definition.
A working code example can be simplified to:
canvas = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:3003", "canv", "memory")
dimY = 20700
dimX = 70000

def colorCanvas(layerInput, dimX, dimY):
    layerInput.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("Id", QVariant.Int)])
    layerInput.updateFields()
    punti = [QgsPointXY(-500, -1000), QgsPointXY(-500, dimY+1000), QgsPointXY(dimX+1000, dimY+1000), QgsPointXY(dimX+1000, -1000)]
    poli = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([punti])
    poligono = QgsFeature(layerInput.fields())
    poligono.setGeometry(poli)
    poligono.setAttributes([1])
    layerInput.dataProvider().addFeatures([poligono])
    layerInput.updateExtents()
    simboloCanvas = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'color':'174,180,183,255', 'outline_color':'35,35,35,255', 'outline_style':'solid', 'outline_width':'0.26', 'outline_width_unit':'MM', 'style':'solid'})
    layerInput.renderer().setSymbol(simboloCanvas)
    layerInput.triggerRepaint()
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layerInput)
        
colorCanvas(canvas, dimX, dimY)

